# TimeoutError Exception in Django Web App When Using Sockets

Tags: python, django, sockets, web-applications

I am encountering a TimeoutError exception in my Django web application when attempting to establish socket connections. The code snippet responsible for this issue is as follows, and it works correctly (detects correctly if the ip is accesible or not). However, the problem is that once I visit this particular section and execute the socket code, the TimeoutError continues to occur in all sections of my web app, even when they don't use the socket functionality. I have imported the 'socket' library and am using it to check if a specific IP is connected. Unfortunately, I cannot replace the socket with a ping command, as I need to deploy this web app on a server that does not have the 'ping' command available. Any insights into why this TimeoutError is propagating across all sections of my web app, and how to resolve it, would be greatly appreciated.

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.5)
# create a socket object
mi_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    # try to connect to endpoint
    bol = mi_socket.connect_ex((ip, port))
    print('ip:', ip)
    print('bol:', bol)
    if bol == 0:
        connected = 'True'
    else:
        connected = 'False'
    mi_socket.close()
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
    mi_socket.close()
    connected = 'False'
```

I have attempted to troubleshoot the persistent TimeoutError in my Django web application when using socket connections. Specifically, I tried commenting out the exception traceback and also experimented with not closing the sockets. The exception continues to appear even after these changes. It's worth noting that despite this recurring exception, my web app still functions correctly. Any insights into why this TimeoutError persists, even when I've modified the code to seemingly avoid it, would be greatly appreciated.

The exception message is the following one:

```
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54881)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Programs\Python\python-3.10.10-amd64\lib\socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\Programs\Python\python-3.10.10-amd64\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\Programs\Python\python-3.10.10-amd64\lib\socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "c:\Programs\Python\python-3.10.10-amd64\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 227, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "c:\Programs\Python\python-3.10.10-amd64\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 237, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "c:\Programs\Python\python-3.10.10-amd64\lib\socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
TimeoutError: timed out
```